# How to add disable option or default option in select box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am using react material in react with `select` component.I want to add first disable option something like “please select item”

Implemented in html like this

```
<select name="tagging">
        <option selected disabled>I'm working</option>
        <option value="Option B">Option B</option>
        <option value="Option C">Option C</option>
</select>
```

How I will achieve this using material + react

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/6836mkjx3

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="searchCriteria">SEARCH CRITERIA *</InputLabel>
            <Select
              value={searchCriteria}
              onChange={event => handleInput(event, "searchCriteria")}
              input={<Input name="searchCriteria" id="searchCriteria" />}
            >
              <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
            <FormHelperText>Some important helper text</FormHelperText>
          </FormControl>
```

here is select example in material
https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it with

```
<MenuItem value="">
  <em>None</em>
</MenuItem>
```

for standard material select and with `<option value="" />` if you are using "native" material select.
Additionaly you can add `disabled` prop.

[Codesandbox example forked from material-ui docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/8lox1px9w0)

Answer (score 2):

https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/#selects
This is what you are looking for
example is given in material ui documentation
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `value=""` for first option in material select.

```
<MenuItem selected disabled value="">
     <em>None</em>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a label

**import**: `import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';`

**Component**: `<InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-disabled-label">Select one</InputLabel>`